# how to break Case statement automatically after three attempts?

Tags: bash, ssh

I am posting my script:

::::::Script::::::

```
clear
echo -e '\E[44m'"Testing case conditions"; tput sgr0
until [ "$vpm" = "n" ]; do
read -p "Do you want to continue (Y/n): " vpm
case $vpm in
"Y" | "y" | "yes" | "Yes" | "YES" | "yES" | "yeS" | "YeS" | "YEs" | "yEs")
read -p "Pass your string: " sin
clear

echo -e '\E[42m'"$sin"; tput sgr0
sleep 3

;;    
"n")
echo "Exit"
;;
* ) 

#echo "Invalid parameter" #At this line if user enter any thing else except of yes /n the script print invalid parameter but I want to break it after 3rd wrong input.** 

;;
esac
done
exit 1
```

I want to exit this script after third input of invalid parameter. Kindly guide me that how it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Put the "Yes" comparison code into a function for clarity (and reuse).

You might do a `for int Retries = 1 to 3`, and `exit`/`break` early if answered.